# Nested loops with conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working on a project where I want to create an array named `full_day[]` to be have an exactly equal length with an array `time_plan[]` after passing through my `day_schedule()`.

Here is  my code:

```js
function day_schedule(){

var time_plan = [{"lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},{"lesson_start":"09:00","lesson_end":"10:00"},{"lesson_start":"10:00","lesson_end":"11:00"},{"lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},{"lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"},{"lesson_start":"13:00","lesson_end":"13:30"},{"lesson_start":"13:30","lesson_end":"14:30"}];

var day = [{"subject_name":"Math-1","lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},{"subject_name":"Phy","lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},{"subject_name":"Engl","lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"}];

var key1 = 'lesson_start';
var key2 = 'lesson_end';
var full_day = [];


for (var d = 0; d < day.length; d++) {
                var start_time = day[d].lesson_start;
                var end_time = day[d].lesson_end;

                for (var i = 0; i < time_plan.length; i++) {
                        var search_key = time_plan[i][key1] == start_time && time_plan[i][key2] == end_time;
                        if (search_key == true) {
                            document.writeln('day matched == ' + day[d],'<br>');
                            full_day.push(day[d]);
                        } else {
                            full_day.push({ 
                                lesson_start: ' ',
                                lesson_end: ' ',
                                subject_name: ' '
                            });
                        }

                    }


                console.log('full day',full_day.length, full_day);


            }
}

day_schedule();
```

i'm expecting a result of

```
full day 7 [
  {
    "subject_name": "Math-1",
    "lesson_start": "08:00",
    "lesson_end": "09:00"
  },
  {
    "lesson_start": " ",
    "lesson_end": " ",
    "subject_name": " "
  },
  {
    "lesson_start": " ",
    "lesson_end": " ",
    "subject_name": " "
  },
  {
    "subject_name": "Phy",
    "lesson_start": "11:00",
    "lesson_end": "12:00"
  },
  {
    "subject_name": "Engl",
    "lesson_start": "12:00",
    "lesson_end": "13:00"
  },
  {
    "lesson_start": " ",
    "lesson_end": " ",
    "subject_name": " "
  },
  {
    "lesson_start": " ",
    "lesson_end": " ",
    "subject_name": " "
  }
];
```

but i cant figure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the iterations all wrong if you want `full_day` size to match `time_plan`.
What you're doing in your code is iterate each element in `day` (3 elements) and for each one of these elements add an object to `full_day` for each element in `time_plan` (7 elements).
So what you get is:

1. First `element` in `day` you add 7 objects to `full_day` (7 elements)
2. Secon `element` in `day` you add another 7 objects to `full_day` (14 elements)
3. Third `element` in `day` you add again 7 objects to `full_day` (21 elements)

If you want to keep the logic you used, I'd suggest you turn your loops the other way around like this:

```js
function day_schedule(){
    var time_plan = [{"lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"09:00","lesson_end":"10:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"10:00","lesson_end":"11:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"13:00","lesson_end":"13:30"},
                     {"lesson_start":"13:30","lesson_end":"14:30"}];

    var day =[{
                  "subject_name":"Math1",
                  "lesson_start":"08:00",
                  "lesson_end":"09:00"
              },
              {
                  "subject_name":"Phy",
                  "lesson_start":"11:00",
                  "lesson_end":"12:00"
              },
              {
                  "subject_name":"Engl",
                  "lesson_start":"12:00",
                  "lesson_end":"13:00"
    }];

    var key1 = 'lesson_start';
    var key2 = 'lesson_end';
    var full_day = [];

    for (var tp = 0; tp < time_plan.length; tp++) {
        var start_time = time_plan[tp].lesson_start;
        var end_time = time_plan[tp].lesson_end;
        var lesson = { 
            lesson_start: ' ',
            lesson_end: ' ',
            subject_name: ' '
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
            var search_key = day[i][key1] == start_time && day[i][key2] == end_time;
            if (search_key == true) {
                lesson = day[i]
            }
        }
        full_day.push(lesson)
    }
    console.log('full day',full_day.length, full_day);
}

day_schedule();
```

As you see, this gives the desired output.
Now, we could also fix the code a bit to make it prettier and use some useful JavaScript `Array` function like `find()`

```js
function day_schedule(){
    var time_plan = [{"lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"09:00","lesson_end":"10:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"10:00","lesson_end":"11:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"},
                     {"lesson_start":"13:00","lesson_end":"13:30"},
                     {"lesson_start":"13:30","lesson_end":"14:30"}
        ];
    var day =[{
                  "subject_name":"Math1",
                  "lesson_start":"08:00",
                  "lesson_end":"09:00"
              },
              {
                  "subject_name":"Phy",
                  "lesson_start":"11:00",
                  "lesson_end":"12:00"
              },
              {
                  "subject_name":"Engl",
                  "lesson_start":"12:00",
                  "lesson_end":"13:00"
        }];
    var full_day = [];

    // Use foreach instead of regular for when you iterate arrays
    for (tp in time_plan) {
        var plan = time_plan[tp]
        var start_time = plan.lesson_start;
        var end_time = plan.lesson_end;
        // Use this function to find a suitable lesson given start and end times
        var lesson = day.find(function(d) {
            var start_matches = d.lesson_start == start_time;
            var end_matches = d.lesson_end == end_time;
            var matches = start_matches && end_matches;
            return start_matches && end_matches;
        }) || { // ... or assing a default empty value
            lesson_start: ' ',
            lesson_end: ' ',
            subject_name: ' '
        };
        full_day.push(lesson)
    }
    console.log('full day',full_day.length, full_day);
}

day_schedule();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create another function to parse the Object and parse it.

```js
function parseObj(o){
  Str = "{<br />";
  var i=0;
  while(i<Object.keys(o).length-1){
    Str += "&ensp;&ensp;"+Object.keys(o)[i]+" : "+o[Object.keys(o)[i]]+",<br />";
    i++;
  }
  Str += "&ensp;&ensp;"+Object.keys(o)[i]+" : "+o[Object.keys(o)[i]]+"<br />}";
  return Str;
}

function day_schedule() {

  var time_plan = [{
    "lesson_start": "08:00",
    "lesson_end": "09:00"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "09:00",
    "lesson_end": "10:00"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "10:00",
    "lesson_end": "11:00"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "11:00",
    "lesson_end": "12:00"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "12:00",
    "lesson_end": "13:00"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "13:00",
    "lesson_end": "13:30"
  }, {
    "lesson_start": "13:30",
    "lesson_end": "14:30"
  }];

  var day = [{
    "subject_name": "Math-1",
    "lesson_start": "08:00",
    "lesson_end": "09:00"
  }, {
    "subject_name": "Phy",
    "lesson_start": "11:00",
    "lesson_end": "12:00"
  }, {
    "subject_name": "Engl",
    "lesson_start": "12:00",
    "lesson_end": "13:00"
  }];
  empty={"
  var key1 = 'lesson_start';
  var key2 = 'lesson_end';
  var full_day = [];


  for (var d = 0; d < day.length; d++) {
    var start_time = day[d].lesson_start;
    var end_time = day[d].lesson_end;

    for (var i = 0; i < time_plan.length; i++) {
      var search_key = time_plan[i][key1] == start_time && time_plan[i][key2] == end_time;
      if (search_key == true) {
        document.writeln('day matched == ' + parseObj(day[d])+'<br>');
        full_day.push(day[d]);
      } else {
        full_day.push({
          lesson_start: ' ',
          lesson_end: ' ',
          subject_name: ' '
        });
      }

    }


 //   console.log('full day', full_day.length, full_day);


  }
}

day_schedule();
```

Comment: what i need is the full_day array to be equal length with time_plan array (in this case should be length of 7) by inserting empty/constant object to full_day[] when there's no match found while comparing time_plan[] with day[].

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `document.write`. That only works on the first render of the page, is a blocking operation, and an accidental use after the page has rendered will wipe off the page. Consider using DOM manipulation. `document.createElement` and `node.appendChild` will be your friends. And avoid nested loops if possible, it's a bad habit to make. Use adjacent loops if possible.

If your ultimate goal is to find the subjects in `day` that are found in your `time_plan`, then what you could do is convert `day` into an object with the time as key using `array.reduce`. It's the only thing that makes your `day` items unique, as well as the only data that could identify it from `time_plan`. Then use `array.map` to convert `time_plan` into an array of subjects.

It's just simple array/object transformations, nothing fancy.

```js
const time_plan = [{"lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},{"lesson_start":"09:00","lesson_end":"10:00"},{"lesson_start":"10:00","lesson_end":"11:00"},{"lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},{"lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"},{"lesson_start":"13:00","lesson_end":"13:30"},{"lesson_start":"13:30","lesson_end":"14:30"}];

const day = [{"subject_name":"Math-1","lesson_start":"08:00","lesson_end":"09:00"},{"subject_name":"Phy","lesson_start":"11:00","lesson_end":"12:00"},{"subject_name":"Engl","lesson_start":"12:00","lesson_end":"13:00"}];

// Convert day into time-day element pairs
// { "08:00-09:00": { "subject_name": "..." }, ... }
const dayMap = day.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[`${v.lesson_start}-${v.lesson_end}`] : v }), {});

// Convert time_plan to its corresponding day element using time
// as key.
const full_day = time_plan.map(v => dayMap[`${v.lesson_start}-${v.lesson_end}`]).filter(v => !!v);

console.log(full_day);
```

There's an `array.filter` at the end of `full_day` to remove entries that do not have a corresponding `day` item.